# How to connect to postgres container inside one network via docker-compose?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I try to up some containers via `docker-compose.yml`.

First, I build java app image. I set up database configurations in `build.gradle` for flyway migration job:

```
def dbUrl = 'jdbc:postgresql://db_postgres:5432/db'
def dbUser = 'user'
def dbPassword = 'pass'
```

Second, I set up `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: "3.9"

services:
  my_service:
    build: .
    restart: on-failure
    ports:
      - "8001:8001"
  db_postgres:
    image: postgres
    restart: always
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: db
      POSTGRES_USER: user
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: pass
      PGDATA: "/var/lib.postgresql/data/pgdata"
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
```

I try to connect database by `db_postgres` container tag inside network. But when I up docker-compose, I get connection error:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection to localhost:5432 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.
```

Why app trying to connect to localhost? How to fix it?

Comment: You must bind this containers to one network using https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/

Comment: As I understand, on compose starts, default bridge network creating, and all containers connect it. Isn't it?

Comment: As @rad11's link indicates, Compose automatically creates a network named `default` and attaches containers to it.  That `dbUrl` looks like it should be correct, if it was getting used.  (The `$PGDATA` setting looks wrong and could cause problems but shouldn't be necessary.)

Comment: Can't find any error in compose. Yes networking should work like that (check with docker network inspect default). Did you ensure that the config is properly consumed in code? Maybe by sending it to console output?